# How to Stretch Font Vertically—INLINE—without \scalebox?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, microtype

Closely Related:

[Stretching text vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67254/stretching-text-vertically)

Is it possible to stretch a font vertically—INLINE—without using `\scalebox`?

For example, I would like to have a paragraph with italicized text, or small caps, but in some instances, I would like those more vertically stretched than usual.  `\scalebox` will just scale a box, rather than a font.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "`\scalebox` will just scale a box, rather than a font."?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - (Funny name.)  If you nest a `\parbox`, `\mbox`, `\fbox`, etc., inside of `\scalebox`, everything inside of the box will be scaled, (obviously).   However, all I want is a single sentence italicized in a paragraph to be in italics, but a little taller, or wider, than normal.    Or, some other font style, (not just italics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, (OP), hacked this answer together after trying to interpret the **`Fontspec`** and **`Libertine`** package documentation.

I am not quite sure how or why this works, but it does ...  If someone could delete these initial comments and add explanation, it would be very helpful, specifically:

1. How do we know which font features are available to a specific font.
2. Is there a catalogue of FontSpec features?  (A Table, perhaps). I just randomly happened upon **`FakeStretch`**, (luckily).
3. What is the difference in using **`\newfontfamily`** or using a new "face"?
4. Etc., Etc.

   ```
   % **********************
   \newfontfamily\MyFont{LinLibertineOI}[FakeStretch=0.75]
       \newcommand{\ApplyFont}[1]{% 
       {\MyFont \large\ (#1)}%
   }%
   ```

Comment: 1. Use the `otfinfo` command or examine the font in FontForge (or a similar program).  2. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304360 and updates in the `fontspec` manual since then.  3. If your font has only one weight and shape, or if you intend to use only one weight and shape, then prefer `\newfontface`.